# Is Payment gateway integration possible in phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I want to implement payment gateway integration in phonegap application for both android and IOS,please help me with the proper steps

Comment: Did you find break through for this? Expecting your's speedy assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PhoneGap PayPal-Plugin iPhone

Here is link of PayPal Plugin for PhoneGap iPhone

1) https://github.com/SnareChops/PayPalPlugin

2) http://www.plugreg.com/plugin/extiris/paymentgateway.io-cordova-plugin

3) https://github.com/extiris/paymentgateway.io-cordova-plugin.git

## PayPal SDK Cordova/Phonegap Plugin iOS/Android

1) https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin

Comment: did any plugin available for phonegap android??

Comment: Don't android and apple have a policy against selling anything on the app without using their in-app payment gateway?