# How to implement Payment gateway in phonegap

Tags: cordova, payment

I want to implement Payment gateway in My application.Did anyone know the procedure to do implement Payment gateway in phonegap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322542/is-payment-gateway-integration-possible-in-phonegap

Comment: Its not Working.While i click android link ,Page not found error is coming->Amit Prajapati

Comment: @JothiSankarNKanakavel did you find the solution of this ques