# How to use CCAvenue payment gateway with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I was trying to use CCAvenue payment gateway with Phonegap. But didn't get any proper documentation on its website or any where.
I know I can use paypal plugin. But I wanted to use CCAvenue in my project.
Even I have sent email to CCAvenue support but didn't get any response from them.
could someone help me with that.

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382870/how-to-implement-payment-gateway-in-phonegap)
[link 2](http://www.officialgates.com/ccavenue-application-development.php)

Comment: Currently ccavenue doesn't have any plugin for cordova but you can try to make a cordova pugin by using their android sdk or u can use https://razorpay.com/mobile/ they have cordova plugin